# Как исправить Яндекс Карту (не отображается полностью)?

Tags: яндекс-карты

[image]

Местами не отображается большая часть/кусок от карты. В частности сверху скрин с сафари. С чем это может быть связано.

```
 function initCatalog() {
        objectsMap = new ymaps.Map("catalog__map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 9,
            controls: []
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search',
            suppressMapOpenBlock: true
        });

        var clusterIconContent = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<span class="cluster-count">$[properties.iconContent]</span>'
        );

        var objectIcon = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div class="placemark-icon">' +
                '<div class="icon__object-price">' +
                    '<div class="icon__rooms-quantity"><div class="icon__rooms-quantity-inner">$[properties.roomsQuantity]</div></div>' +
                    '<span class="price">$[properties.price]</span></div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );

        ymaps.option.presetStorage.remove('default#image')
        ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('objects#group', {
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            iconImageHref: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
            iconImageSize: [133, 23],
            iconImageOffset: [-20, 0],

            iconContentLayout: objectIcon,
            hideIconOnBalloonOpen: true,
            clusterIcons: [{
                href: "images/cluster-icon.png",
                size: [50, 50],
                offset: [-20, -20],
                shape: {
                    type: 'Circle',
                    coordinates: [0, 0],
                    radius: 20
                }
            }],
            clusterIconContentLayout: clusterIconContent
        });

        clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
            preset: 'objects#group',
            gridSize: 128,
            hasBalloon: false,
            hasHint: false,
            groupByCoordinates: false,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: false,
            clusterHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
            geoObjectHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
            maxZoom: 13
        });

        var objectIcon = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div class="placemark-icon placemark-icon-address">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
        );



    var ZoomLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<button class="btn_plus" id="zoom-in">'+
            '<i class="icon icon-plus"></i>'+
        '</button>'+
        '<button class="btn_minus" id="zoom-out">'+
            '<i class="icon icon-minus"></i>'+
        '</button>'
        , {

        build: function () {
            ZoomLayout.superclass.build.call(this);

            $('#zoom-in').bind('click', ymaps.util.bind(this.zoomIn, this));
            $('#zoom-out').bind('click', ymaps.util.bind(this.zoomOut, this));
        },

        clear: function () {
            $('#zoom-in').unbind('click');
            $('#zoom-out').unbind('click');

            ZoomLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
        },

        zoomIn: function () {
            var map = this.getData().control.getMap();
            this.events.fire('zoomchange', {
                oldZoom: map.getZoom(),
                newZoom: map.getZoom() + 1
            });
        },

        zoomOut: function () {
            var map = this.getData().control.getMap();
            this.events.fire('zoomchange', {
                oldZoom: map.getZoom(),
                newZoom: map.getZoom() - 1
            });
        }
    });

        places.map(function() {
            var card = $(this);
            var lat = card.data('lat'), lng = card.data('lng');
            if ( lat !== '' && lng !== '' ) {
                placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([lat, lng], {
                    balloonContent: '<div class="last-apartments__loading">' +
                                        '<div class="lds-rolling">' +
                                            '<div></div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>'
                }, {
                    preset: 'objects#group'
                });

                placemark.icon = '';
                placemark.properties.set('id', card.data('key'));
                placemark.properties.set('roomsQuantity', card.find('span.rooms').data('rooms-quantity'));
                placemark.properties.set('price', card.find('.last-apartments__card-price .price').html());

                placemark.events.add('click', function (e) {
                    var thisPlacemark = e.get('target');

                    $.get(
                        "/catalog/get-object-by-id",
                        { objectId: thisPlacemark.properties.get('id') },
                        function (response) {
                            $('.last-apartments__loading').css('display', 'none');
                            thisPlacemark.properties.set('balloonContent', response);
                        }
                    );

                });

                clusterer.add(placemark);
            }
        });

        objectsMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
        geoObjectsQuery = ymaps.geoQuery(clusterer.getGeoObjects());



        searchMetroId = $('.search__metro-id').val();
        if ( searchMetroId !== '' )
            getMetroById(searchMetroId);

        objectsMap.events.add('actionend', function(e) {
            updateCatalogByFilter( geoObjectsQuery.searchInside(objectsMap) );
        });


        zoomControl = new ymaps.control.ZoomControl({options: {layout: ZoomLayout}});
        objectsMap.controls.add(zoomControl, {left: 10, top: 10});
    }
```

Comment: Я взял ваш код, вставил в jsfiddle и не вижу проблемы http://jsfiddle.net/vdeL3bz5/ . Можно ссылку на сайт или поправьте код на странице http://jsfiddle.net/vdeL3bz5/ чтобы проблема воспроизводилась.

Comment: Вот сайт. Сейчас попробую воспроизвести на jsfiddle 
https://etinot.ru/catalog

Comment: Не получается воспроизвести на сайте, что нужно сделать? Что за браузер используете и операционную систему?

Comment: Браузер к примеру mozilla на windows, либо на safari на mac.

Comment: Попробуйте почистить кэш. Воспроизводится после этого тут jsfiddle.net/vdeL3bz5 ? Воспроизводится ли на другом компьютере? Воспроизводится ли из другой сети, например через мобильный интернет?